# casting fails when using mongoose-schema-extend, with a nested object at the base schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a base schema
which has an embedded schema name as one of its fields:

```
var associatesSchema = BaseMongoOperationsSchema.extend({
    type: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: NameSchema
    }
});
```

a second schema extends it:

```
var AssociatesInfoSchema = AssociatesSchema.extend({
    source : String,
    confidence : mongoose.Schema.Types.Double,
    resultId : String,
    rating : {type:Number,default:undefined}
});
```

and the corresponding models:

```
var Associates mongoose.model('Associates', associatesSchema);    
var AssociatesInfo mongoose.model('AssociatesInfo', associatesInfoSchema);

var associate = new Associates();
associate.name = new Name();
```

FAILS for casting reasons (the pathType of name is 'Real' whereas it's supposed to be 'Nested')

any known way to solve this?
(changing the schema type from NameSchema to [NameSchema]  seems to solve it...but obviously that's not a proper way to solve this)

Comment: Did you try 
var associate = {
  ...
  name: {
    ... 
  }
}
?

without new Name()